# Should I use a Berkeley professor's recommendation with other colleges?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I recently received a letter of recommendation from a well known Berkeley professor. My question is, would it be wise to apply to other universities with that letter of recommendation, or would the college(s) be bitter about that?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.  What is the possible source of bitterness?

Answer (score 3):

Did the professor just give you a generic recommendation letter? Why?

Professors are supposed to write you letters to a variety of departments, if you are applying for MA or PhD programs. If you're an undergrad (or MA student) at Berkeley and are applying for graduate programs at other departments, it is completely normal and expected that you'll submit letters of recommendation from your Berkeley professors to non-Berkeley departments. Why would other departments be bitter about that? Where else would they potentially expect you to submit from?